# uwsgi starts 2 processes instead of 1

Tags: uwsgi

Trtying to run flask app using uwsgi. After run uwsgi starts 2 processes, instead of 1.

This is how I run uwsgi:
`uwsgi --http :8080 --wsgi-file app.py --callable app`

Here is start output:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Fri Aug 30 11:51:22 2019] ***
compiled with version: 7.4.0 on 19 August 2019 13:14:50
os: Linux-4.15.0-1029-gcp #31-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 21 09:40:28 UTC 2019
nodename: *********
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/***********
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 2225
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8080 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 19721)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:43257 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35)  [GCC 7.3.0]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x563599d74540
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72904 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x563599d74540 pid: 19720 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 19720, cores: 1)
```

I

Actual result:

```
ps aux | grep uwsgi
******** 19720  1.2  3.8  73440 22908 pts/1    S+   11:51   0:00 uwsgi --http :8080 --wsgi-file app.py --callable app
******** 19721  0.0  0.1  34496   696 pts/1    S+   11:51   0:00 uwsgi --http :8080 --wsgi-file app.py --callable app
******** 19726  0.0  0.1  14856   980 pts/0    S+   11:51   0:00 grep --color=auto uwsgi
```

Expected: one uwsgi process is running

Comment: If killing first process, the second is also killed. Killing first doesn't kill second.